# com.mongodb.DBObject / BSON serializer for java

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, bson

Hi anyone knows of a Java library to help serialize/deserialize a `com.mongodb.DBObject` into a `BSON` binary and vise-versa?

Comment: Have you looked at the MongoDB docs for their class library? http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html (In particular the `BasicBSONEncoder`/`Decoder` here: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html?org/bson/BasicBSONEncoder.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple, you can use the following helper methods:

```
public static byte[] encode(BSONObject bsonObject) {
    BSONEncoder encoder = new BasicBSONEncoder();
    return encoder.encode(bsonObject);
}

public static BSONObject readObject(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    BasicBSONDecoder encoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
    return encoder.readObject(is);
}

public static BSONObject readObject(byte[] bsonObject) {
    BasicBSONDecoder encoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
    return encoder.readObject(bsonObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need binary BSON, i.e., byte array in BSON format, you may use the following pair:

```
public byte[] DBObjectToBSON(DBObject dbObject) {
    BasicBSONEncoder encoder = new BasicBSONEncoder();
    return encoder.encode(dbObject);
}

public DBObject BSONToDBObject(byte[] bson) {
    BasicBSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
    JSONCallback callback = new JSONCallback();
    decoder.decode(bson, callback);
    return (DBObject) callback.get();
}
```